# Creating Instances of Software in Subdomains a la Freshbooks - Help

Tags: codeigniter

We are building a niche project management software in CodeIgniter. We want to give each user their own subdomain on our site. For example, user.oursite.com. User1 goes to user1.oursite.com to log into their software. This is the same format that BaseCamp and Freshbooks use for each instance of their software.

Here is the question. What is the best practice for building a site like this? Here are some concerns:

1) CSS, PHP, and other files. Every instance of the software will be identical, except the database (discussed below). In other words, each instance (i.e., user1.oursite.com, user2.oursite.com) will use identical php files and CSS. Anything custom to a user will be pulled dynamically from the database. How can we format these subdomains to minimize the effort it will require to push updates to the file? One idea we had was to create a master set of files that every subdomain draws from (i.e., a mirror) and of course create a new database for each of these subdomains. How can this be accomplished? Is this best practice? Any other suggestions?

2) Databases -- the master database for the base project management software is fairly complex. As discussed above, each user gets their own instance of the software (i.e., username1.oursite.com, username2.oursite.com, username3.oursite.com). Should each instance of the software have its own database? What happens when we need to update / modify a database (say, for example, add a new table) across 100 users?

3) Codeigniter -- How will Codeigniter perform under this type of structure? Should we have any concerns?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. If you can point me to documentation or discussion about these types of software-builds, that would be fantastic. If anybody can do this for us, we'd be interested in chatting with you.

Comment: I was hoping to see some replies by now! Have you had any luck with this yet?

Answer (score 0):

1) If you code is identical (only data changes), then you just point all your subdomains to the same instance of codeigniter. In your `application/config/config.php` set base_url to blank:

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
```

so codeigniter will figure out your domain by itself.

Then you can retrieve the current subdomain in your code with:

```
$current_subdomain = $this->input->server('SERVER_NAME');
```

and use that to load whatever user specific data you want.

stuff like CSS and images and Javascript, its probably a good idea to keep somewhere else.. like `http://static.yoursite.com` so their browser will cache it across all your subdomains.

3) I just tried what i said in 1) with CodeIgniter 2.0 and it appeared to work fine. I cant really think of any issues it would have. I mean, the DNS is resolved long before CodeIgniter gets involved.

If you are worried about horizontal scalability of your system, thats a different issue, but you should probably look into Amazon AC3 or something.